# Not getting an sed error

Tags: linux, sed

Im trying to append a line in a file using following sed command

```
    sed -i  's/id="1asda"/id="1asda"\n peer="120"/g' a.xml.
```

Now the problem is that even if I'm giving a wrong id, sed is not popping an error.How to get an error if the pattern is not found.

Comment: As an aside, if this is an XML attribute, there are much better ways to run the update (ie. `xmlstarlet ed -u "//*[@id="1asda"]/@id" -v "120"`. That lets you limit it to only replace the ids of specific elements, or things that are at specific places in the hierarchy, and is guaranteed not to result in output that isn't valid XML.

Comment: The `\n` for a newline works in the *pattern* of a substitution, but not in an address or the replacement string.  Instead, you might try printf-style quoting if you're using bash (or another shell that does the same thing): `sed  $'s/id="1asda"/id="1asda"\\\n peer="120"/g' a.xml`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is used to replace text. Having nothing to replace is not an error.

Use something like `grep` to check whether there's something to replace or not. For example:

```
if grep -q 'id="1asda"' a.xml
then
    sed -i  's/id="1asda"/id="1asda"\n peer="120"/g' a.xml
else
    echo 'nothing to do' >& 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{e=1}gsub(/foo1/, "bar",$0){e=0};1;END{exit e}' file
```

The above command will give you a return value of `1` if no substitution has been performed, otherwise `0`.